# PHP SOAP-Client returns CGI-Error at more than 30 MB response

Tags: php, windows, web-services, soap

I have a question for an PHP/SOAP-Client issue. I've searched already for a solutions at stackoverflow.com but I haven't found something what leads me to a solutions.

I have wrote an PHP-Soap-Client which sends requests to an .NET-Webservice. One function of this Webservice is to receive documents. Every thing works fine until the received document isn't larger than 30 MB. If I try to get a document larger than 30 MB then the server returns the CGI-Error.

The server where I run that PHP-Soap-Client is an Windows 2003 Standard with IIS6. PHP-Version is 5.2.17 (sorry for that. I know that version is an old one but I can't update PHP because of some needed extensions).

Did anybody had such an issue and solved it? Or has anybody maybe a solution for it?

Best regards
Markus

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: It only returns

CGI Error

The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers.

Nothing more :-(

I have tested the request with SoapUI and there everything is correct... ResponseHeader, ResponseBody... .

Comment: I don't quite understand what the PHP SOAP client does exactly. Whether it downloads that huge reply or uploads some large document to the webservice. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try verify the values of the [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) properties in your `php.ini` and see if they are causing the constraints.

They should look something like this in your `php.ini`"

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Something to be aware of, and to quote the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size):

> To upload large files, this value (`post_max_size`) must be larger than
>   `upload_max_filesize`. If memory limit is enabled by your configure
>   script, `memory_limit` also affects file uploading. Generally speaking,
>   `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've set all your suggested values to 60 M (biggest filesize which can be received from the webserver) and the memory limit to 512M then it works.

Comment: @MarkusTamler Awesome. If you like my answer, please consider upvoting and accepting it. Thanks!